# Take username and Products on batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Can I take the username and list products installed in the same txt file?

I thought of something like:

```
for /f  "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a in (`wmic product get name`) do (
    set "result=%%a"
)

echo %username%/%result% > test.txt
```

But no success.

I need this to put this on an Excel file, with another program, and I need this structure, username/programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can absolutely do that, you just need to keep in mind that `for` loops process one line at a time, so you need to output the value while you're still in the loop.

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('wmic product get name') do (
    echo %%A >>test.txt
)
```

You don't need to set a variable for this since you aren't doing any string manipulation with it, but if you did, you would have to use delayed expansion:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims=" %%A in ('wmic product get name') do (
    set "line=%%A"
    echo !line! >>test.txt
)
```

---

You can also skip the `for` loop altogether and just redirect the output of the `wmic` command straight to the text file:

```
wmic product get name >>test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(
for /f  "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a in (`wmic product get name`) do (
    echo %username%/%%a
)
)> test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) from [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) or your [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), to get this information as a single line in CSV file in the format:

```
"UserName","Program Name 1","Program Name 2", "Program Name 3", etc…
```

Example command:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "'\"' + (@($([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\')[-1])) + (Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Product -Filter 'Name Is Not Null').Name -Join '\",\"') + '\"'" 1> "UserProducts.csv"
```